# When i creates new configurable products the product page not opening

Tags: magento-1.8

When i created new products as configurable products, the products are being displayed on catalog list page but when we open product page the page is not opening and showing "No data received" and Reload Page.

I have done with all settings in product settings. cleared cache, Reindexed URL Rewrite, But still unable to open the newly created product page.

Please give any solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: If it's online, please post the link to that product page

Comment: Thank you. Please check this http://sweetkad.com/kad-kahwin/vimp.html for product list page and this is page not opening http://sweetkad.com/kad-kahwin/vimp/vimp-0005.html

Answer (score 0):

The product is loading, but taking too much time! May be the image resolution and size is taking too much time to fetch from server. Please Speed up your Magento, or, try loading it through any proxy server.
[image]